# TreeView populates on its own and crashes Access

Tags: ms-access, treeview, vba

My problem is a tree view in my Access 2002 application.

It is already populated, when I open the form. Which is strange, because the only code that adds the nodes is bound to a button.

Also, only part of the data is shown and when I switch between tabs () the data inside the tree view duplicates/doubles. When I then hit any other tab Access crashes instantly just like * zap *

Is it maybe necessary to clean a tree view all along?

Any other ideas what the problem could be - solutions also welcome ;)

Cheers,
Ramon

Comment: There is no native Access treeview control and few professional developers that I know use it. It's too bad MS hasn't done a better job on that front, as it's such a familiar and useful interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your suggestions.

I still did not found out why data is loaded into the TreeView, but I came up with a solution.

First I started to clean up the TreeView when the form is loaded. 

That really did some good to stability. Now it is possible to click around without crashing Access.

When data is loaded to the TreeView the old behaviour shows up again. Switching between tabs adds more data and finally crashes Access.

It seems like the TreeView (Version 6.0) is rebuilding itself without cleaning up properly. 
Based on this assumption, I now clear and rebuild the TreeView when switching to the containing tab.

I am still interested in the root cause, but its working now.

Thanks again,
Ramon

Answer (score 1):

I have come across this problem and traced it down to the treeview control does not like being on a tab page. You will have to redesign your form to keep the treeview outside the tab.

If it has to appear to be on a tab page then you could try .......

Placing the treeview behind the tab control.
Setting the background of the tab control to transparant.
On the "On Change" event of the tab control get it to check which tab is being selected.
If it is the tab you want then set the treeview to visbale if not then hide it

Answer (score 1):

I use a VCL (Delphi/BCB) wrapper as Tree View control on a tab (TTreeView on a TPageControl).

My program hangs once I call TreeView1.Items.Clear .
But only in 'certain' cases! Especially if I expand an item and then try to Clear() all the items. If I never touch any node (or only scroll) it's fine.

I discovered that setting the selected node to NULL just before calling Items.Clear resolved it for me.

Interestingly, calling Clear() caused a few OnChange events to occur for some reason, which was not expected (since we were deleting all the nodes anyway!)...

Answer (score 0):

First, find out why the TreeView is loading when you haven't told it to yet.
Step through your code. You have to solve this first.

Second, does the form crash if you don't load the TreeView but do switch Tabs?

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe this problem still persists and no fix was published by Microsoft! I have faced this same issue with Windows 8.1 running Office 2010

In any case, the simplest workaround that I reached (and which probably saves resources) was to build the TreeView of the currently active tab in the form's "On Current Event".

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Select Case Me.tabCompany.Value 'Return Page Index of active page
        Case 0  ' Page Index for Page 1.
            Call TVPage1
        Case 1  ' Page Index for Page 2.
            Call TVPage2
    End Select
End Sub
```

Another thing to keep in mind is to run the same routine to update the TreeView while switching from one page to another in "On Change Event" of the tab:

```
Private Sub tabCompany_Change()
    Select Case Me.tabCompany.Value 'Return Page Index of active page
        Case 0  ' Page Index for Page 1.
            Call TVPage1
        Case 1  ' Page Index for Page 2.
            Call TVPage2
    End Select
End Sub
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

MsAccess 2016/Win10 still crashes while switching between Tabs with TreeView controls on different Tabs.
My initial wrong approach was to clear nodes **after** leaving a Tab - as I do with sub forms located on different tabs (save resources).

```
Private Sub MainTabCtrl_Change()
'Activate selected/called Tab
Select Case Nz(Me![MainTabCtrl],0)
Case 0 'Tab 1
    Me![SubFormTab1].Form.RecordSource = "tblSubFormData"
    Me.TreeViewTab1.Object.Nodes.Clear
    Call BuildTreeView1
Case 1 'Tab 2
    Me.TreeViewTab2.Object.Nodes.Clear
    Call BuildTreeView2
End Select
'Deactivate leaving Tab
Select Case Nz(Me![PriorTab],0)
Case 0 'Tab 1
    Me![SubFormTab1].Form.RecordSource = ""
    'Do nothing with TreeView1
Case 1 'Tab 2
    'Do nothing with TreeView2
End Select
Me![PriorTab] = Me![MainTabCtrl]
End Sub
```

Clear TreeView nodes (if needed) on calling Tab, instead to clear nodes in TreeView on leaving Tab.